# What is a trapped pdf?

Tags: hyperref, pdf

I noticed in the [`hyperref` documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) that there is an entry for `pdftrapped` in the `hypersetup`.

I went over google to find out what it was, but all I came up with was this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/latexusersgroup/rXrrHOpbbxU  which, in my opinion, does not answer the question.

So, what is a trapped pdf? Why are we able to set it up with `hyperref`?  What does it mean for our .pdf document? and how does it translate to our printed version?

Comment: How about this? [http://indesignsecrets.com/indesigns-trapping-in-a-composite-pdf.php](http://indesignsecrets.com/indesigns-trapping-in-a-composite-pdf.php).  The Adobe site also has several PDFs you can download directly

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_%28printing%29).